# ¿Por qué imprimir una lista es diferente a imprimir sus elementos por separado?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Quería preguntar que por qué Python2.7 vierte diferente resultado al realizar estas dos acciones:

```
lista= ["Hola", "ò.ó"]
print lista
print lista[0],lista[1]
```

En el primer `print` devuelve:

```
['Hola', '\xc3\xb2.\xc3\xb3']
```

Y en el segundo:

```
Hola ò.ó
```

Mi duda realmente es por qué en el primer caso devuelve '\xc3\xb2.\xc3\xb3' y qué debo hacer para que devuelva una lista con ['Hola', 'ò.ó'].

Llevo un rato con encodes y decodes pero no hay manera de entenderlos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No es un problema de encoding en absoluto, es una característica del lenguaje. Explicado a grandes rasgos:

Cada objeto puede tener dos representaciones diferentes: una representación amigable con el usuario final, retornada por el método  `__str__`y una representación pensada para el programador y para procesos de depuración, implementada en  `__repr__`. La primera tiene como objetivo ser legible, la segunda ser explícita y sin ambigüedad.

Cuando haces `print(lista[0])` estas llamado en realidad el método `__str__` del objeto `str`. En cambio, cuando haces `print(list)` estas llamado a los métodos `__repr__` de tus objetos contenidos en la lista.

`__repr__` retorna una representación del objeto que normalmente puede ser pasada a `eval` para que se reconstruya el objeto correspondiente. En otras palabras, suele ser código Python válido.

Podemos ver este comportamiento de forma directa sobre una cadena:

```
>>> cad = "ò.ó"
print cad
ò.ó
>>> repr(cad)
'\xc3\xb2.\xc3\xb3'
>>> cad = u"a"
>>> print cad
a
>>> repr(cad)
"u'a'"
```

Vemos como `repr` nos retorna la "representación interna" del objeto.

Es un comportamiento intencional. Si tenemos la lista `["Hola, mundo", "manzanas"]` seria confuso imprimirla usando `__str__` ya que obtendríamos: `[Hola, mundo, manzanas]`.

Si quieres imprimirlo como comentas existen varias formas. Una forma de hacerlo, siempre que todos tus elementos de la lista sean cadenas, es:

```
>>> lista= ["Hola", "ò.ó"]
>>> print "[{}]".format(', '.join('"{}"'.format(cad) for cad in lista))

["Hola", "ò.ó"]
```

---

Podemos crear nuestra propia clase para ver el comportamiento arriba indicado de los métodos `__str__` y `__repr__`:

```
class Fraccion:
    def __init__(self,  numerador,  denominador):
        self.num = numerador
        self.den = denominador

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}/{}".format(self.num, self.den)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Fraccion({}, {})".format(self.num, self.den)
```

Vamos a ver como se comporta nuestra clase:

```
>>> f = Fraccion(1, 2)  # Creamos un objeto instanciando nuestra clase

>>> print(f)
>>> 1/2

>>> repr(f)            
Fraccion(1, 2)

>>> l = [f]             # Creamos una lista que contiene nuestro objeto
>>> print(l)    
[Fraccion(1, 2)]
```