# Pandas , selec_index.loc[] misma sentencia, resultados diferentes al imprimir

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.x

No entiendo el por qué consigo presentaciones de resultados tan dispares con estas dos sentencias que, en principio, son iguales (ini = 0 en el script):

```
>>> print (selec_index.loc[0, "Fecha"])
2017-09-12 00:00:00

>>> print ("Fecha de inicio del analisis : ", selec_index.loc[ini, "Fecha"])
('Fecha de inicio del analisis : ', Timestamp('2017-09-12 00:00:00'))
```

Por otro lado, ¡qué complicado es el manejo de fechas en python para los más inexpertos!. ¿ Cómo puedo conseguir que en lugar de "Timestamp....", me presente la fecha en éste formato "2017-09-12"?.

¿Conocéis algún documento/Web, que muestre de forma clara ejercicios de cambio de unos formatos a otros en Python-Pandas?. Gracias

Comment: Hola efueyo, ese comportamiento con la información que das solo es reproducible en Python 2, no en Python 3.Si es así, en estos casos deberías añadir la etiqueta `python-2.x` o `python-2.7`. También es aconsejable que de no tener grandes inconvenientes te pases a Python 3, Python 2 no va a recibir mejoras de importancia y dejará de tener soporte en 2020 por lo que se recomienda ir dejándolo de lado paulatinamente. La gran mayoría de librerías están portadas y desarrolladas para Python 3 en la actualidad, incluso Ubuntu en su última versión trae Python 3 como intérprete del sistema por defecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es prácticamente seguro que estás usando Python 2 (en Python 3 este comportamiento no es así, al menos con el ejemplo que proporcionas). Tu problema no tiene nada que ver con Pandas ni con el tratamiento de las fechas por parte de este, es debido a como usas `print`. En Python 2 `print` no es una función por lo que no debes usar paréntesis como en Python 3:

```
>>> print "hola", 4
hola 4
```

**Si usas paréntesis y pasas al menos dos objetos separados por una coma** estás en realidad **creando una tupla** e imprimiendola posteriormente. Cuando imprimes una tupla, sus elementos se muestran según la salida de sus métodos `__repr__` en vez de `__str__`, por eso te imprime 
`Timestamp(...)`. Mírate esta publicación si te interesa conocer más sobre esto:

[¿Por qué imprimir una lista es diferente a imprimir sus elementos por separado?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/111217/15089)

Podemos ver este comportamiento de forma muy simple con el ejemplo anterior:

```
>>> print("hola", 4)
('hola', 4)
```

Simplemente no uses paréntesis con `print` en Python 2, y obtendrás la misma salida en ambos casos:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> ini = 0
>>> selec_index = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(pd.Timestamp('now'), periods=4),  columns = ["Fecha"])

>>> selec_index
                       Fecha
0 2017-11-12 22:34:09.111527
1 2017-11-13 22:34:09.111527
2 2017-11-14 22:34:09.111527

>>> print selec_index.loc[0, "Fecha"]
2017-11-12 22:32:29.687000
>>> print "Fecha de inicio del analisis : ", selec_index.loc[ini, "Fecha"]
Fecha de inicio del analisis :  2017-11-12 22:32:29.687000
```

Si quieres especificar un formato a tu gusto usa `strftime`:

```
>>> print "Fecha de inicio del analisis : ", selec_index.loc[ini, "Fecha"].strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
Fecha de inicio del analisis :  12/11/2017
>>> print "Fecha de inicio del analisis : ", selec_index.loc[ini, "Fecha"].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
Fecha de inicio del analisis :  2017-11-12
```