# Eliminar prefijo unicode (u) de fichero JSON con Python

Tags: python, json, unicode

Estoy intentando leer un fichero JSON con Python 2.7. Para ello, voy leyendo línea a línea y extraigo los campos que me interesan.

Pero estoy teniendo problemas porque me aparece el prefijo unicode (u) en algunos campos.

```
{u'quote_count': 0, u'contributors': None, u'truncated': False, u'name': u'Pilar Espinosa'}
```

He pensado en reemplazar el caracter  `u'` por `'` con replace pero me ha dado problemas en algunas cadenas.

¿Cómo podría quitarlo de otra forma?

Comment: El prefijo solo indica que es una cadena unicode, no es parte de la cadena en sí, por lo que de nada sirve que intentes un reemplazo. Se agrega de cara al usuario para indicar que se trata de una cadena unicode por parte de su método [`__repr__`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/111217/15089) y no `str` (ASCII en Python 2).

Comment: En ese caso, la trataré como si de una cadena se tratase.

Answer (score 0):

```
{u'quote_count': 0, u'contributors': None, u'truncated': False, u'name': u'Pilar Espinosa'}
```

Eso no es JSON (al menos JSON válido). Cualquiera diría que es simplemente la forma textual de un `dict` de Python. Sí, muy parecido a JSON, pero no es lo mismo.

Cargar dicho `dict` es posible sin tener que leer línea a línea. Si damos por hecho que el texto está en una variable `a`

```
mydict = eval(a)
```

La evaluación ya se encarga de cargar las cadenas de texto en formato unicode automáticamente.

Por supuesto y si uno no tiene el control de la fuente de la que procede el archivo, `eval` puede no ser adecuado, porque está realmente ejecutando código (todo es código básicamente en Python)