# Problema al escapar el carácter \

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente contenido en un archivo JSON

```
{
  "password": "xxx\\\xxx"
}
```

y lo estoy cargando desde Python con el siguiente código

```
data = json.loads(open(file_path).read())
```

cuando imprimo el resultado lo que obtengo es esto

```
>>> print(json.dumps(data))
{'password': 'xxx\\\xxx'}
```

no esta escapando el carácter `\`, ¿alguna solución?

Comment: ¿Cómo que no está escapando? Es exactamente lo que deberías ver, una única barra... Si imprimieras el valor de `data["password"]` verías una única barra

Comment: Tienes razón, no explique bien, la salida de json.dumps(data) era con la que obtenía la cadena sin escapar el carácter pero me estaba complicando al hacerlo de esa forma

Comment: Entonces sigo sin entender la pregunta @Roman... Está bien que cuando se imprime un objeto, o cuando se imprime en formato JSON la barra aparezca escapada, es la sintaxis correcta... ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado?

Comment: como mencionaba cuando ocupo json.dumps(data) me devuelve un string pero con la barra sin escapar así 'xxx\\xxx' y el resultado esperado es así 'xxx\xxx'

Comment: Antes que nada, estás usando los términos al revés, ```\\``` es cuando está escapada :-) Pero `json.dumps()` serializa a un objeto (lo convierte en string) en formato JSON... En JSON, una barra tiene que estar escapada **siempre**.... Por más que te lo esté imprimiendo así, significa que el contenido real es una **única** barra... Por eso, al imprimir la propiedad directamente con `data["password"]` verías una sola barra no escapada

Comment: Cierto tienes razón es mi error estaba confundiendo las cosas, como dices, así debe ser la salida del comando.

Comment: Bien, genial que se entendiera... Agrego que si quisieras, podrías reemplazarlo manualmente, pero la verdad no es lo recomendable, porque estarías rompiendo el formato JSON, haciendo que no pueda volver a ser deserializable, y no te dejaría diferenciar entre valores como ```"\\n"``` (una barra seguida de una n) y ```"\n"``` (un salto de línea)

Comment: Posible duplicado de https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/111217/15089. En este caso es una lista y no un diccionario pero la razón de por qué imprime la barra inclinada es exactamente la misma, `dict` no implementa el método `__str__` por lo que `print` usa `__repr__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que estás viendo no tiene nada qué ver con JSON en realidad, sino con la forma en que python determina qué debe mostrar cuando imprimes una variable con `print()`. Si lo que imprimes no es un "tipo básico" (como un entero o una cadena), lo que hace `print()` es generar lo que se llama la "representación" del objeto (que sí es una cadena) y mostrarla.

Cada objeto define su propia forma de cómo debe ser representado (mediante su método `__repr__()`), pero por defecto muchos de ellos lo implementan de modo que lo que muestran sea compatible con lo que escribirías en tu código fuente para introducir uno de esos datos.

Por ejemplo, si tienes `lista = [1,2,3]`, cuando haces `print(lista)`, lo que hace realmente es imprimir `repr(lista)`, que es una forma de representar esa lista en forma de cadena de caracteres, y que sería en este caso `'[1, 2, 3]'`.

En el caso de las cadenas de caracteres esto puede dar lugar a confusiones, especialmente en lo que respecta a los caracteres "escapados".

Por ejemplo:

```
>>> texto = "Esto es una prueba\r\nOtra línea"
```

La secuenci `\r` realmente es un solo caracter. Es una forma de introducir el ascii 13. Lo mismo para `\n` que es el ascii 10. Cuando haces `print(texto)`, esos caracteres especiales (ascii 10 y 13) causan un retorno de carro y nueva línea respectivamente, por lo que verás en la salida el texto:

```
>>> print(texto)
Esto es una prueba
Otra línea
```

Sin embargo, si haces `print(repr(texto))`, entonces obtendrás una *representación* de la variable, que sea compatible con código python, y lo que verías en este caso sería:

```
>>> print(repr(texto))
'Esto es una prueba\r\nOtra línea'
```

Es decir, pone comillas alrededor y escapa de nuevo los caracteres especiales de modo que lo que sale es equivalente a lo que pusiste cuando inicializaste la variable.

Otro ejemplo, más relacionado ya con tu pregunta:

```
>>> ruta = 'a\\b'
```

El doble `\\` en realidad representa un solo carácter, como sabemos (está "escapado"). Es necesario hacerlo así porque de lo contrario, si tras el `\` apareciera por ejemplo una `r`, se tomaría por el ASCII 13 como vioms antes (de hecho `\b` en el ejemplo, es otro carácter especial, el ASCII 7 o "campana"). Cuando aparece otro `\` se codifica como el ASCII 92 que es el código del `\`. Por tanto la variable `ruta`  es una cadena de tres caracteres que son `a`,`\` y `b`, almacenados respectivamente en `ruta[0]`, `ruta[1]` y `ruta[2]`.

Si imprimes la variable, verás `a\b`, pero si imprimes `repr(ruta)` verás `'a\\b'`, entrecomillado y escapado para que sea python válido.

```
>>> print(ruta)
a\b
>>> print(repr(ruta))
'a\\b'
```

Ahora bien. Si esa variable forma parte de otra estructura de datos, por ejemplo, de un diccionario:

```
>>> dic = {'ruta': ruta }
```

Cuando quieras imprimir esa variable con `print(dict)`, ya que `dict` no es una cadena ni un entero, python imprimirá en realidad `repr(dict)`, el cual internamente llamará a `repr()` para ir volcando cada campo. Por eso verás:

```
>>> print(dict)
{'ruta': 'a\\b'}
>>> print(repr(dict))
{'ruta': 'a\\b'}
```

Y eso es lo que puede liarte. La variable contiene solo un `\`, pero su *representación* requiere dos.

Comment: excelente respuesta ahora me queda todo claro.