# Mostrar datos de una tabla de Access en Tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, ms-access, interfaz-gráfica

Muy buenos días, tengo una incógnita con respecto a mi código de Python, la cosa es que tengo un programa con interfaces en Tkinter que tiene una conexión a una base de datos de access. Hasta aqui todo normal, puedo ingresar datos y obtenerlos de vuelta (como un tipo reporte).

El problema viene cuando quiero ver los datos almacenados, ya que me los muestra de una forma muy poco entendible y hasta cierto punto "primitiva", porque los datos que retorna si bien son los que se encuentran en la base de datos, los muestra separados con caracteres y comas, en lugar de mostrarlos separados por casillas (como ocurre en Access).

El código que muestra los datos es el siguiente:

```
def ventana_reporte():
t3=Toplevel(ventana,bg="#E8C8CD")
t3.title("Reporte")
t3.geometry('500x500')
t3.configure(bg="#E8C8CD")
t3.focus_set()
t3.grab_set()
t3.transient(master=ventana)

clientes_label=Label(t3,text="------Clientes Registrados-------",background="#ECCCCE")
clientes_label.pack(side=TOP)
data_label=Label(t3,text="Marca\tFacebook\t Instagram \t Twitter \t\tCorreo \t\t Página web")
data_label.pack(side=TOP)
vent1=Listbox(t3)
vent1.config(width=0,height=0,background="#ECCCCE")
vent1.pack()

cursor.execute("SELECT Clientes.Marca,Facebook,Instagram,Twitter,Correo,Web FROM Clientes")
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    vent1.insert(END,row)  
proyecto_label=Label(t3,text="------Proyectos Registrados-------",background="#ECCCCE")
proyecto_label.pack(side=TOP)
data_label1=Label(t3,text="Proyecto \tMarca  \t\t Sitio Web  \t\t Correo\t\t Teléfono")
data_label1.pack(side=TOP)

vent2=Listbox(t3)
vent2.config(width=0,height=0,background="#ECCCCE")
vent2.pack()
cursor.execute("SELECT Proyectos.Proyecto,Marca,Paquete FROM Proyectos")
for row in cursor.fetchall():
   vent2.insert(END,row)
```

Y así es como se muestran los datos en la ventana:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi duda es, ¿Qué tengo que cambiar para ver los datos como si fueran casillas?, es decir, mostrarlos de manera ordenada según los encabezados que están en la ventana (es decir, que marca, facebook, instagram, etc)

Answer (score 2):

El widget `Listbox` permite mostrar una lista de items seleccionables, no permite *per se* mostrar datos tabulados con diferentes columnas. Generalmente la opción para estos casos es usar [`ttk.Treeview`](http://%20#%20-*-%20coding:%20utf-8%20-*-%20%20import%20Tkinter%20as%20tk%20import%20tkFont%20import%20ttk%20'''%20#===========%20Python%203%20============#%20import%20tkinter%20as%20tk%20from%20tkinter%20import%20ttk%20import%20tkinter.font%20as%20tkFont%20'''%20%20import%20tkinter%20as%20tk%20from%20tkinter%20import%20ttk%20import%20tkinter.font%20as%20tkFont%20%20%20%20%20class%20Table(tk.Frame):%20%20%20%20%20def%20__init__(self,%20parent=None,%20title=%22%22,%20headers=[],%20height=10,%20*args,%20**kwargs):%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20tk.Frame.__init__(self,%20parent,%20*args,%20**kwargs)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self._title%20=%20tk.Label(self,%20text=title,%20background=%22#ECCCCE%22,%20font=(%22Helvetica%22,%2016))%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self._headers%20=%20headers%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self._tree%20=%20ttk.Treeview(self,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20height=height,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20columns=self._headers,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20show=%22headings%22)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self._title.pack(side=tk.TOP,%20fill=%22x%22)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20#%20Agregamos%20dos%20scrollbars%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vsb%20=%20ttk.Scrollbar(self,%20orient=%22vertical%22,%20command=self._tree.yview)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20vsb.pack(side='right',%20fill='y')%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20hsb%20=%20ttk.Scrollbar(self,%20orient=%22horizontal%22,%20command=self._tree.xview)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20hsb.pack(side='bottom',%20fill='x')%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self._tree.configure(xscrollcommand=hsb.set,%20yscrollcommand=vsb.set)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self._tree.pack(side=%22left%22)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20header%20in%20self._headers:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self._tree.heading(header,%20text=header.title())%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self._tree.column(header,%20stretch=True,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20width=tkFont.Font().measure(header.title()))%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20def%20add_row(self,%20row):%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self._tree.insert('',%20'end',%20values=row)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20i,%20item%20in%20enumerate(row):%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20col_width%20=%20tkFont.Font().measure(item)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20self._tree.column(self._headers[i],%20width=None)%20%3C%20col_width:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20self._tree.column(self._headers[i],%20width=col_width)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20def%20ventana_reporte(parent=None):%20%20%20%20%20t3%20=%20tk.Toplevel(parent,%20bg=%22#E8C8CD%22)%20%20%20%20%20t3.title(%22Reporte%22)%20%20%20%20%20t3.geometry('500x500')%20%20%20%20%20t3.configure(bg=%22#E8C8CD%22)%20%20%20%20%20t3.focus_set()%20%20%20%20%20t3.grab_set()%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20clientes_headers%20=%20(u%22Marca%22,%20%20%20u%22Facebook%22,%20u%22Instagram%22,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20u%22Twitter%22,%20u%22Correo%22,%20%20%20u%22P%C3%A1gina%20web%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20clientes_tab%20=%20Table(t3,%20title=%22Clientes%20Registrados%22,%20headers=clientes_headers)%20%20%20%20%20clientes_tab.pack()%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20#cursor.execute(%22SELECT%20Clientes.Marca,Facebook,Instagram,Twitter,Correo,Web%20FROM%20Clientes%22)%20%20%20%20%20cursor%20=%20((u%22Marca%20A%22,%20u%22Facebook%20A%22,%20u%22Instagram%20A%22,%20u%22Twitter%20A%22,%20u%22aaa@mail.com%22,%20u%22www.aaa.com%22),%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(u%22Marca%20B%22,%20u%22Facebook%20B%22,%20u%22Instagram%20B%22,%20u%22Twitter%20B%22,%20u%22bbb@mail.com%22,%20u%22www.bbb.com%22)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20row%20in%20cursor:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20clientes_tab.add_row(row)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20proyectos_headers%20=%20(u%22Proyecto%22,%20u%22Marca%22,%20u%22Paquete%22)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20proyectos_tab%20=%20Table(t3,%20title=%22Proyectos%20Registrados%22,%20headers=proyectos_headers)%20%20%20%20%20proyectos_tab.pack()%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20#cursor.execute(%22SELECT%20Proyectos.Proyecto,Marca,Paquete%20FROM%20Proyectos%22)%20%20%20%20%20cursor%20=%20((u%22Proyecto%20A%22,%20u%22Marca%20A%22,%20%22Paquete%20A%22),%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20(u%22Proyecto%20B%22,%20u%22Marca%20B%22,%20u%22Paquete%20A%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20row%20in%20cursor:%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20proyectos_tab.add_row(row)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ventana%20%20=%20tk.Tk()%20ventana_reporte(parent=ventana)%20ventana.mainloop()).

Dejo un ejemplo simplificado usando una clase derivada de `tkinter.Frame` que permite mostrar datos tabulados mostrando un título, encabezados de columnas, con ancho de columna ajustado automáticamente al texto insertado y con *scrollbars*:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont
import ttk
'''
#=========== Python 3 ============#
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
'''


class Table(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, title="", headers=[], height=10, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self._title = tk.Label(self, text=title, background="#ECCCCE", font=("Helvetica", 16))
        self._headers = headers
        self._tree = ttk.Treeview(self,
                                  height=height,
                                  columns=self._headers, 
                                  show="headings")
        self._title.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill="x")

        # Agregamos dos scrollbars 
        vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self._tree.yview)
        vsb.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal", command=self._tree.xview)
        hsb.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')

        self._tree.configure(xscrollcommand=hsb.set, yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
        self._tree.pack(side="left")

        for header in self._headers:
            self._tree.heading(header, text=header.title())
            self._tree.column(header, stretch=True,
                              width=tkFont.Font().measure(header.title()))

    def add_row(self, row):
        self._tree.insert('', 'end', values=row)
        for i, item in enumerate(row):
            col_width = tkFont.Font().measure(item)
            if self._tree.column(self._headers[i], width=None) < col_width:
                    self._tree.column(self._headers[i], width=col_width)
```

El ejemplo es básico y se puede mejorar mucho, pero para empezar tenemos un resultado decente, un ejemplo basado en tu código:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import Tkinter as tk
import tkFont
import ttk
'''
#=========== Python 3 ============#
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
'''


class Table(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, title="", headers=[], height=10, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self._title = tk.Label(self, text=title, background="#ECCCCE", font=("Helvetica", 16))
        self._headers = headers
        self._tree = ttk.Treeview(self,
                                  height=height,
                                  columns=self._headers, 
                                  show="headings")
        self._title.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill="x")

        # Agregamos dos scrollbars 
        vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self._tree.yview)
        vsb.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal", command=self._tree.xview)
        hsb.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')

        self._tree.configure(xscrollcommand=hsb.set, yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
        self._tree.pack(side="left")

        for header in self._headers:
            self._tree.heading(header, text=header.title())
            self._tree.column(header, stretch=True,
                              width=tkFont.Font().measure(header.title()))

    def add_row(self, row):
        self._tree.insert('', 'end', values=row)
        for i, item in enumerate(row):
            col_width = tkFont.Font().measure(item)
            if self._tree.column(self._headers[i], width=None) < col_width:
                    self._tree.column(self._headers[i], width=col_width)



def ventana_reporte(parent=None):
    t3 = tk.Toplevel(parent, bg="#E8C8CD")
    t3.title("Reporte")
    t3.geometry('500x500')
    t3.configure(bg="#E8C8CD")
    t3.focus_set()
    t3.grab_set()

    clientes_headers = (u"Marca",   u"Facebook", u"Instagram",
                        u"Twitter", u"Correo",   u"Página web"
                        )


    clientes_tab = Table(t3, title="Clientes Registrados", headers=clientes_headers)
    clientes_tab.pack()

    #cursor.execute("SELECT Clientes.Marca,Facebook,Instagram,Twitter,Correo,Web FROM Clientes")
    cursor = ((u"Marca A", u"Facebook A", u"Instagram A", u"Twitter A", u"aaa@mail.com", u"www.aaa.com"),
              (u"Marca B", u"Facebook B", u"Instagram B", u"Twitter B", u"bbb@mail.com", u"www.bbb.com")
              )

    for row in cursor:
        clientes_tab.add_row(row)

    proyectos_headers = (u"Proyecto", u"Marca", u"Paquete")

    proyectos_tab = Table(t3, title="Proyectos Registrados", headers=proyectos_headers)
    proyectos_tab.pack()

    #cursor.execute("SELECT Proyectos.Proyecto,Marca,Paquete FROM Proyectos")
    cursor = ((u"Proyecto A", u"Marca A", "Paquete A"),
              (u"Proyecto B", u"Marca B", u"Paquete A"
               )
              )

    for row in cursor:
       proyectos_tab.add_row(row)




ventana  = tk.Tk()
ventana_reporte(parent=ventana)
ventana.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Está excelente el ejemplo que tu me das, muchas gracias enserio, pero surge otra duda, como hago para extraer los datos directamente de la base de datos? ya que por lo que veo los introdujiste manualmente, no se obtuvieron desde la base de datos.

Comment: @LuisTovar los introduje manualmente para que el ejemplo sea reproducible sin tener que crear o tener acceso a una bd, si eliminas las lineas  `cursor = ((u"Marca A", ...))` y descomentas `#cursor.execute("SELECT...)` debería funcionar si el driver de la base de datos sigue las convenciones. Si no funciona comenta,

Comment: Al descomentar cursor.execute y borrar las lineas que pusiste, obtengo un mensaje de error:

TclError: wrong # args: should be "font measure font ?-displayof window? text"

Comment: @LuisTovar coloca al inicio del ciclo `for row in cursor:` estas dos líneas: `print type(row)` y `print repr(row)` y muestra lo que te imprimen justamente antes del error. ¿Si en vez de `for row in cursor:` haces `for row in cursor.fetchall():` tienes también el mismo error?. Por cierto, ¿qué driver usas para conectarte a la bd? Al iterar sobre `cursor` se debe ir obteniendo el contenido de cada fila en forma de un iterable (tupla, lista, etc)  que contenga las cadenas a insertar en cada celda de esa fila, es decir `row` debería ser algo así `(u"Proyecto A", u"Marca A", "Paquete A")`

Comment: Estoy usando pyodbc para establecer la conexión a la base de datos, y Microsoft Access Driver como driver, al hacer cursor.fetchall(): como dices, ya me muestra los datos dentro de la bd, y lo que obtengo en la consola a partir según los comandos print que me dices obtengo esto:

<type 'pyodbc.Row'>
(u'asd', u'asd', u'asd', u'asd', u'asd', u'asd', u'asd')

y en la lista me muestra los datos así como dices, con este formato:
(u"Proyecto A", u"Marca A", "Paquete A")

Comment: En todo caso, lo que quiero es que me muestre los datos sin los caracteres tales como las u y las comas

Comment: Las 'u' y las comillas no forman parte de la cadena, son consecuencia de imprimir una tupla y la consecuente  llamada al método `__repr__` de las cadenas que contiene, solo sirven para denotar una cadena unicode, ver: [¿Por qué imprimir una lista es diferente a imprimir sus elementos por separado?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/111217/15089)

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero gracias por el aporte, a mi personalmente me ha ido bastante bien.Al abrir la ventana me sale como otra pequeña ventana que se queda abierta sin ninguna utilidad, como se quita?? Soy bastante nuevo en esto y se me hace un poco cuesta arriba. Un saludo!