# Mostrar datos de tabla sqlite3 en un DataGridView

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite3

¿Como voy a mostrar un `DataGridView` en Tkinter? Tengo el siguiente código:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import sqlite3

root = Tk()
root.title("Gestión BBDD")
root.geometry("300x400+500+300")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

##------------------------VARIABLES---------------------------

##------------------------FUNCIONES---------------------------


def conectar():
    miConexion = sqlite3.connect("DATOSUSUARIOS")
    miCursor = miConexion.cursor()
    try:
        miCursor.execute("""
            CREATE TABLE DATOSUSUARIOS (
            ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NULL,
            NOMBRE_USUARIO VARCHAR(50),
            PASSWORD VARCHAR(50),
            APELLIDO VARCHAR(50),
            DIRECCION VARCHAR(50),
            COMENTARIO VARCHAR (250))
            """)
        messagebox.showinfo("Gestión BBDD", "¡¡BBDD creada con éxito!!")
    except sqlite3.OperationalError:
        messagebox.showinfo("Gestión BBDD", "¡¡La BBDD ya fue creada!!")
    miConexion.commit()
    miConexion.close()

def leer():
    miConexion = sqlite3.connect("DATOSUSUARIOS")
    miCursor = miConexion.cursor()
    miCursor.execute("SELECT ID FROM DATOSUSUARIOS WHERE NOMBRE_USUARIO='reza'")
    usuarios = miCursor.fetchall()
    textComentario.delete(1.0,END)
    textComentario.insert(1.0,(usuarios))

    '''
    for ii in usuarios:
        if ii[0] == int(textID.get()):
            textNombre.set(ii[1])
            textPassword.set(ii[2])
            textApellido.set(ii[3])
            textDireccion.set(ii[4])
            textComentario.insert(1.0,[ii[5]])
    '''
    miConexion.commit()
    miConexion.close()

##-------------------------BOTONES---------------------------
botonLeer = Button(root, text="Leer", command=leer)
botonLeer.place(x=70,y=350)





root.config(menu=menuBarra)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Tkinter (hay más frameworks gráficos para Python) no tiene `DataGridView`, sin embargo puedes usar `ttk.Treeview` si solo vas a mostrar los datos, en esta respuesta tienes un ejemplo:https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/172386/15089. También podrías crear la tabla  con `tkinter.Label` y `tkinter.Entry` manualmente.

Comment: gracias por su ayuda