# Sincronizar selección en varios Listbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

¿Cómo puedo seleccionar un item en primer `Listbox` que por efecto automáticamente selecciona en otro `Listbox` el item con el mismo índice?

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.titel="selecionar en dos list box"
root.geometry("600x600+20+10")
def CurSelet(event):
    widget = event.widget
    items= widget.curselection()
    print(items)
    listbox2.insert(0,items)

label1=Label(root, text="List 1")
label1.place(x=20,y=20)
listbox1=Listbox(root)
listbox1.place(x=20,y=40)
itemsforlistbox=['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven']
listbox1.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',CurSelet)

label3=Label(root, text="List 2")
label3.place(x=350,y=20)
listbox3=Listbox(root)
listbox3.place(x=350,y=40)

for items in itemsforlistbox:
    listbox1.insert(END,items)
    listbox3.insert(END,items)

label2=Label(root, text="List 2")
label2.place(x=190,y=20)
listbox2=Listbox(root)
listbox2.place(x=190,y=40)



root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero de todo, por defecto el usuario puede seleccionar texto, o un ítem en este caso, con el ratón y el texto seleccionado se exportará al portapapeles. Esto imposibilita la selección simultánea en varios `ListBox`. Para deshabilitar este comportamiento basta con usar el argumento `exportselection=False`.

Hecho lo anterior, el siguiente paso es enlazar el evento `'<<ListboxSelect>>'` con una función en aquellos `ListBox` en los que quieras este comportamiento. Luego en esta función puedes obtener los índices de los items seleccionados mediante el método `tkinter.Listbox.curseselection`. Esto ya lo haces en tu caso correctamente, lo único que te falta es iterar sobre la tupla anterior y usando `tkinter.Listbox.selection_set` seleccionar esos mismo índices en el resto de `ListBox`.

Puede ser más cómodo y más portable usar una lista en la que agregas los diferentes `Listbox` que van a compartir selección e iterar sobre ella en vez de "hardcodear" cada uno de ellos en la función.

Este es un ejemplo simplificado basado en tu código:

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.titel="selecionar en dos list box"
root.geometry("400x250+20+10")
listbox_list = []

def on_select(event):
    global listbox_list
    
    widget = event.widget
    items = widget.curselection()
    
    for listbox in listbox_list:
        if listbox != widget:
            listbox.selection_clear(0, tk.END)
            for index in items:
                listbox.selection_set(int(index))
    
    
label1 = tk.Label(root, text="List 1")
label1.place(x=30, y=20)
listbox1 = tk.Listbox(root, exportselection=False, selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE)
listbox1.place(x=30, y=40)
listbox_list.append(listbox1)

label2 = tk.Label(root, text="List 2")
label2.place(x=200,y=20)
listbox2 = tk.Listbox(root, exportselection=False, selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE)
listbox2.place(x=200, y=40)
listbox_list.append(listbox2)


listbox1.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', on_select)
listbox2.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', on_select)

items = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven']
for items in items:
    listbox1.insert(tk.END, items)
    listbox2.insert(tk.END, items)


root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si la intención es mostrar datos tabulados sería oportuno crear nuestro propio widget en una clase propia que se encargara de manejar los distintos `Listbox` (columnas) así como facilitar la agregación y eliminación de datos (filas o columnas). No obstante, `ttk.Treeview` es posiblemente más apropiado y simple de implementar en este caso, ver:

[Mostrar datos de una tabla de Access en Tkinter](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/172226/15089)

> **Nota:** en el código anterior se ha usado el modo de selección múltiple (`selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE`) a modo de ejemplo, pero el funcionamiento es exactamente el mismo para cualquiera de los modos de selección posibles (`SINGLE` (por defecto), `BROWSE`, `MULTIPLE` y `EXTENDED` ), aunque obviamente todos los `Listbox` deben compartir el mismo modo para su correcto funcionamiento.