# Como mostrar un dataframe en tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

soy novato en esto de las interfaces graficas, estoy elaborando un programa bastante rudimentario.
Lo que necesito es imprimir un dataframe en el recuadro señalado en la imagen, este no tiene porque ser un cuadro de texto (ya he dicho que tengo bastante poca idea).

De momento el codigo que tengo es este:

```
stats_ult=self.df_resultados[self.df_resultados.Local==equipo].iloc[:,:7].head()
self.tinfo_loc_ult.delete("1.0", END)
self.tinfo_loc_ult.insert("1.0",str(stats_ult))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no te importa instalar módulos externos [`pandastable`](https://github.com/dmnfarrell/pandastable) es una magnífica solución.

Instala desde pip simplemente:

> python -m pip install pandastable

No solo permite mostrar de forma ridículamente simple DataFrames, sino también editarlos, incluye por defecto barras de herramientas con botones que perimiten exportarlos/importarlos a csv o excel, pivotar, filtrar, copiar al portapaeles, graficar, etc...

Además de poder modificar muchos aspectos visuales como colores, fuente, tamaño de celdas, etc.

Un ejemplo muy básico:

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd
from pandastable import Table, TableModel




class DataFrameTable(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, df=pd.DataFrame()):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.table = Table(
            self, dataframe=df,
            showtoolbar=False,
            showstatusbar=True,
            editable=False)
        self.table.show()


df = pd.DataFrame({"Foo": (1, 2, 3, 4), "Bar": (7, 13, 17, 19)})
root = tk.Tk()
table = DataFrameTable(root, df)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Usando un widget Text, puedes usar la salida de `pandas.DataFrame.to_string`:

```
import tkinter as tk
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({"Foo": (1, 2, 3, 4), "Bar": (7, 13, 17, 19)})

root = tk.Tk()
table = tk.Text(root)
table.insert(tk.INSERT, df.to_string())
table.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otra opción con más trabajo sería usar un widget `ttk.TreeView`, algo similar a esto:

- [Mostrar datos de una tabla de Access en Tkinter](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/172386/15089)

Hay más opciones como renderizar HTML mediante [cefpython](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython) y usar `pandas.DataFrame.to_html()`, por ejemplo.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por la respuesta, me ha sido de gran utilidad ;). Un saludo