# ¿Cómo puedo borrar los datos que se cargaron en las tablas de tree view en python?

Tags: python, tkinter, tablas, table

me ha surgido un problema en un tramo de mi programa, resulta que necesito limpiar la tabla con un boton y no logro hacerlo, ya intente haciendo:

`for row in cursor
      clientes_tab.delete(row)`

pero me larga error de que las tablas no tienen un atributo "delete", probe llamando a `self._tree.delete(row)` y tampoco. No se donde estoy fallando, quizas estoy haciendo mal algo, necesito ayuda. La idea de poder limpiar la tabla es para posterior agregar un boton para buscar campos especificos, ya que sin limpiar la tabla cuando busco especificamente me crea otra tabla debajo de la misma y me desconpagina todo. Muchas Gracias. Aca dejo el codigo donde creo las tablas y hago la consulta:

```
#---Definimos la funcion para abrir "ENTRADAS (PLANILLAS)"---

class Table(tk.Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent=None, title="", headers=[], height=20, *args, **kwargs):
      tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
      self._title = tk.Label(self, text=title, background="#F7F2E0",height=2, pady=5)
      self._headers = headers
      self._tree = ttk.Treeview(self,
                                height=height,
                                columns=self._headers, 
                                show="headings")
      self._title.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill="x")

    # Agregamos dos scrollbars 
    vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self._tree.yview)
    vsb.pack(side='right', fill='y')
    hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient="horizontal", command=self._tree.xview)
    hsb.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')

    self._tree.configure(xscrollcommand=hsb.set, yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
    self._tree.pack(side="left")

    for header in self._headers:
        self._tree.heading(header, text=header.title())
        self._tree.column(header, stretch=True,
                          width=tkFont.Font().measure(header.title()))

def add_row(self, row):
    self._tree.insert('', 'end', values=row)
    for i, item in enumerate(row):
        col_width = tkFont.Font().measure(item)
        if self._tree.column(self._headers[i], width=None) < col_width:
                self._tree.column(self._headers[i], width=col_width)


def consulta():

    conn = pymysql.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="",
    database="DBDistribuidora")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT Fecha, Codigo, Nombre, Marca, Cantidad, Precio FROM entrada_consignacion")
    return cursor
    conn.close()


 def entrada_reporte():

      t3 = tk.Toplevel()#ventana principal
      t3.title("INVENTARIO")
      t3.geometry('530x650')
      t3.resizable(False,False)
      t3.focus_set()
      t3.grab_set()

clientes_headers = ("Fecha", "Codigo", "Nombre","Marca","Cantidad","Precio")
clientes_tab = Table(t3, title="ENTRADAS DE MERCADERIAS", headers=clientes_headers)
clientes_tab.pack()

cursor = consulta()#aquí trae el resultado de la consulta a la BD

#Aquí carga la tabla
for row in cursor:
    clientes_tab.add_row(row)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que la clase `Table` es un `Frame` (hereda de él), no un `ttk.Treeview`, la clase me recordaba a algo:

- [Mostrar datos de una tabla de Access en Tkinter](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/172226/15089)

no se me ocurrió en aquel momento agregar un método para limpiar el `Treeview` a pesar que es muy simple, debes usar el método `tkinter.ttk.TreeView.delete()` como efectivamente intentabas, pero sobre el `Treeview` (`self._tree`) no sobre la instancia de `Table` y pesarle una lista con todos los items que ya tiene(no los resultados de la consuta) los cuales puedes obtener con el método `tkinter.ttk.TreeView.get_children()`. Lo suyo es implementar el método en la clase:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter.font as tkFont


class Table(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(
           self, parent=None, title="", headers=[],
           height=20, *args, **kwargs
           ):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self._title = tk.Label(
            self, text=title, background="#F7F2E0", height=2, pady=5
            )
        self._headers = headers
        self._tree = ttk.Treeview(
            self, height=height, columns=self._headers, show="headings"
            )
        self._title.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill="x")

        # Agregamos dos scrollbars
        vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self._tree.yview)
        vsb.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        hsb = ttk.Scrollbar(
            self, orient="horizontal", command=self._tree.xview
            )
        hsb.pack(side='bottom', fill='x')

        self._tree.configure(xscrollcommand=hsb.set, yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
        self._tree.pack(side="left")

        for header in self._headers:
            self._tree.heading(header, text=header.title())
            self._tree.column(
                header, stretch=True,
                width=tkFont.Font().measure(header.title())
                )

    def add_row(self, row):
        self._tree.insert('', 'end', values=row)
        for i, item in enumerate(row):
            col_width = tkFont.Font().measure(item)
            if self._tree.column(self._headers[i], width=None) < col_width:
                self._tree.column(self._headers[i], width=col_width)

    def clear(self):
        self._tree.delete(*self._tree.get_children())
```

Un ejemplo reproducible:

```
import random


def consulta():
    for _ in range(random.randint(1, 13)):
        yield random.choices(range(1, 200), k=2)


def nueva_consulta():
    cursor = consulta()
    clientes_tab.clear()
    for row in cursor:
        clientes_tab.add_row(row)


t3 = tk.Tk()
clientes_headers = ["foo", "bar"]
clientes_tab = Table(
    t3, title="ENTRADAS DE MERCADERIAS", headers=clientes_headers
    )
clientes_tab.pack()
tk.Button(t3, text="Nueva consulta", command=nueva_consulta).pack()

t3.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La clase no está pensada para modificar el número de columnas, en este caso puedes eliminar el widget completo y crear otra nueva tabla o habría que modificar la clase para que permita modificar las columnas una vez creada.

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias! me acabas de salvar la vida!! :D