# Como puedo introducir una tabla de 10 columnas en Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy haciendo un programa para hacer un Balance General el cual en total son 10 columnas.
Estoy intentando usar la funcion de Tkinter Treeview() pero solo me muestra 2 de esas columnas. Como seria para mostrar todas?

Aca dejo el pedazo de codigo:

```
def balance(self):
    # Ventana de balance
    self.balance_wind = Toplevel()
    self.balance_wind.title('Balance de 8 columnas')


    # Table
    self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.balance_wind, height=10, columns=10)
    self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0)
    self.tree.heading('#0', text='Numero', anchor=CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#1', text='Cuenta', anchor=CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#2', text='Debe', anchor=CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#3', text='Haber', anchor=CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#4', text='Deudor', anchor=CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#5', text='Acreedor', anchor=CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#6', text='Activo', anchor=CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#7', text='Pasivo', anchor=CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#8', text='Positivo', anchor=CENTER)
    self.tree.heading('#9', text='Negativo', anchor=CENTER)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es un error muy típico y muy comprensible por cierto, el argumento `columns`  no se usa para indicar el número de columnas que quieres que tenga el `TreeView`, no de forma directa mediante un entero. En cambio espera una secuencia de cadenas (`str`) con identificadores para cada columna. Los identificadores serán usados internamente para identificar las columnas, teniendo en cuenta que la primera columna tiene siempre '# 0' como identificador, las que agregues mediante `columns` se agregarán a ésta primera columna.

Al hacer  `columns=10` lo que haces es agregar una única columna aparte de `"#0"` con `"3"` como identificador, resultado, dos columnas solo.

Si quieres usar la columna `#0`, necesitas pasar una lista con nueve cadenas a modo de identificador, lo que hará un total de diez columnas.

```
self.tree = ttk.Treeview(
    self.balance_wind, height=10, columns=[f"#{n}" for n in range(1, 10)]
    )
```

Si quieres descartar la primera columna puedes hacer en cambio lo siguiente:

```
self.tree = ttk.Treeview(
    self.balance_wind, height=10, columns=[f"#{n}" for n in range(1, 11)]
    )
self.tree.config(show='headings')
self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0)
self.tree.heading('#1', text='Numero', anchor=CENTER)
self.tree.heading('#2', text='Cuenta', anchor=CENTER)
self.tree.heading('#3', text='Debe', anchor=CENTER)
self.tree.heading('#4', text='Haber', anchor=CENTER)
self.tree.heading('#5', text='Deudor', anchor=CENTER)
self.tree.heading('#6', text='Acreedor', anchor=CENTER)
self.tree.heading('#7', text='Activo', anchor=CENTER)
self.tree.heading('#8', text='Pasivo', anchor=CENTER)
self.tree.heading('#9', text='Positivo', anchor=CENTER)
self.tree.heading('#10', text='Negativo', anchor=CENTER)
```

Comment: Y como hago para hacer que las columnas sean menos anchas? Porque me cubren toda la pantalla y no se llegan a ver todas. @FJSevilla

Comment: Puedes calcular el espacio mínimo para cada columna y de ser necesario usar scrollbars, mirate la clase implementada para mostrar tablas de datos de ésta respuesta mía a otra pregunta, puede ayudarte: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/172386/15089